# how to add id of another model in the controller on active record association in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

i have to make a hotel booking system so i made a user,hotel and booking model and given all necessary association . in the booking model i have given user and hotel:references
so while creating a new booking in the create method in the booking_controller i have given @booking.user = current_user as provided by the devise gem.
how can i provide the hotel_id in the controller.

this is the schema.rb

```
    create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "user_id", null: false
        t.string "guest_name"
        t.integer "no_of_guest"
        t.integer "room"
        t.date "check_in_date"
        t.date "check_out_date"
        t.integer "hotels_id", null: false
        t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.index ["hotels_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_hotels_id"
        t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id"
      end
```

this is the link to create booking form

```
<%= link_to 'Book Now', new_booking_path(:id => @hotel.id), :class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm' %>
```

booking_controller.rb

```
def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking successfully !!!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

how and where should i set the particular hotel id to the booking?

Answer (score 1):

The Rails way to do this is by creating [a nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :hotels do
  resources :bookings, shallow: true
end
```

This creates the routes `GET /hotels/:hotel_id/bookings/new` and `POST /hotels/:hotel_id/bookings` and the named helper `new_hotel_booking_path`.

```
<%= link_to 'Book Now', new_hotel_booking_path(@hotel), class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm' %>
```

Adjust your controller so that you create set the hotel in a callback and the build the booking off the hotel:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_hotel, only: [:new, :index, :create]

  # GET /hotels/1/bookings/new
  def new
    @booking = @hotel.bookings.new
  end

  # POST /hotels/1/bookings
  def create
    @booking = @hotel.bookings.new(booking_params) do |b|
      b.user = current_user
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking successful' }
        format.json { status: :created, location: @booking } # send either a Location header or a response entity - not both
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_hotel
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
  end 

  # ...
end
```

Pass an array to create nested resources with a form:

```
# Rails < 5.1
<%= form_for([@hotel, @booking]) do |f| %>

# Rails 5.1+
<%= form_with(model: [@hotel, @booking]) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have `booking` model like below:

```
class Booking
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hotel
......
end
```

I assume you have a `hotel` list in the page or have `hotel` object and in front of that you have `Book Now` link. In the code you have passed `id` as parameter, but you should pass `hotel_id` instead of `id`.

```
<%= link_to 'Book Now', new_booking_path(hotel_id: @hotel.id), :class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm' %>
```

Then in `booking_controller.rb` you must have `booking_params` method along with `create` and `new` methods.

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  @booking.hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
end

def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params.merge!(user: current_user))
  respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking successfully !!!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
end

private
def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :hotel_id, add_other_fields_you_want_to_save)
end
```

Comment: Its one way to do it but definitely not the Rails way.